# Return cell outside if-else

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i encounter a problem when I return the cell outside the if-else it gives me an error of "Use of unresolved identifer 'cell'". Here's my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let feedItem = feeds.objectAtIndex(UInt(indexPath.row)) as? FeedsDataModel {
        if feedItem.media_url != "" {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithImageCell
            cell.setupCellWithFeedItem()
        }
        else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithoutImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithoutImageCell
            cell.setupCellWithFeedItem()
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `feeds` really an optional or unknown type? If the table view is designed in Interface Builder the data source array is supposed to be a non-optional object of one specific type and the optional binding is not needed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use like

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if let feedItem = feeds.objectAtIndex(UInt(indexPath.row)) as? FeedsDataModel {
    if feedItem.media_url != "" {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithImageCell
        cell.setupCellWithFeedItem()
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithoutImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithoutImageCell
        cell.setupCellWithFeedItem()
        return cell
    }


}
}
```

**Update**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let cell: FeedsTableViewWithImageCell

if let feedItem = feeds.objectAtIndex(UInt(indexPath.row)) as? FeedsDataModel {
    if feedItem.media_url != "" {
         cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithImageCell
        cell.setupCellWithFeedItem()

    }
    else {
         cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithoutImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithoutImageCell
        cell.setupCellWithFeedItem()

    }


}
     return cell
}
```

**Edit & update**

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if let feedItem = feeds.objectAtIndex(UInt(indexPath.row)) as? FeedsDataModel {
    var cell:FeedsTableViewWithImageCell!
    if feedItem.media_url != "" {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithImageCell
        cell.setupCellWithFeedItem()
    }
    else {
       let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithoutImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithoutImageCell
        cell1.setupCellWithFeedItem()
         return cell1
    }

    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: this gives me an error of "Missing return function"

Comment: on the else condition it gives me an error of "Cannot assign value of type "FeedsTableWithoutImageCell" to type "FeedsTableWithImageCell"

Comment: Yeah! This is what Im looking for

Answer (score 1):

the cell must be a global variable in scope.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let feedItem = feeds.objectAtIndex(UInt(indexPath.row)) as? FeedsDataModel {
        var cell:FeedsTableViewWithImageCell!
        if feedItem.media_url != "" {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithImageCell
            cell.setupCellWithFeedItem()
        }
        else {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithoutImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithoutImageCell
            cell.setupCellWithFeedItem()
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't work. There is also a `FeedsTableViewWithoutImageCell` type and the cell is clearly supposed to be non-optional.

Comment: changed my answer to unwrap variable, it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     var cell: FeedsTableViewWithImageCell?
    if let feedItem = feeds.objectAtIndex(UInt(indexPath.row)) as? FeedsDataModel {
        if feedItem.media_url != "" {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithImageCell
            cell.setupCellWithFeedItem()
        }
        else {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithoutImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithoutImageCell
            cell.setupCellWithFeedItem()
        }


    }
return cell!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write below line of code. Your problem will be solved.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell?
    if let feedItem = feeds.objectAtIndex(UInt(indexPath.row)) as? FeedsDataModel {
        if feedItem.media_url != "" {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithImageCell
            cell.setupCellWithFeedItem()
        }
        else {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithoutImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithoutImageCell
            cell.setupCellWithFeedItem()
        }
    }

    return cell!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `cell` variable declared in `if` scope. It is not visible out of this scope. You have two options how to fix it:

1. Return `cell` in same scope

   ```
   if let feedItem = feeds.objectAtIndex(UInt(indexPath.row)) as? FeedsDataModel {
       if feedItem.media_url != "" {
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithImageCell
           cell.setupCellWithFeedItem()
           return cell
       }
       else {
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithoutImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithoutImageCell
           cell.setupCellWithFeedItem()
           return cell
       }
   }
   ```
2. declare variable before `if` scope

   ```
   var cell: FeedsTableViewWithImageCell?
   if let feedItem = feeds.objectAtIndex(UInt(indexPath.row)) as? FeedsDataModel {
       if feedItem.media_url != "" {
           cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithImageCell
           cell.setupCellWithFeedItem()
       }
       else {
           cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableWithoutImgCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedsTableViewWithoutImageCell
           cell.setupCellWithFeedItem()
       }
   }
   return cell
   ```